# Remove all classes that begin with a certain string

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div with `id="a"` that may have any number of classes attached to it, from several groups. Each group has a specific prefix. In the javascript, I don't know which class from the group is on the div. I want to be able to clear all classes with a given prefix and then add a new one. If I want to remove all of the classes that begin with "bg", how do I do that? Something like this, but that actually works:

```
$("#a").removeClass("bg*");
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

With jQuery, the actual DOM element is at index zero, this should work

```
$('#a')[0].className = $('#a')[0].className.replace(/\bbg.*?\b/g, '');
```

Comment: Careful with this one. Word boundary splits on dash character ('-') and dots and others, so class names like "bg.a", "bg-a" etc. will not be removed but replaced with ".a", "-a" etc. So if you have classnames with punctuation characters you may run into trouble by just running a simple regex replace. Here is a SO thread [about word boundary definition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324676/what-is-a-word-boundary-in-regexes)

Comment: Kabir Sarin's answer below with split(' ') and indexOf is better IMO because it won't cause those special-charactered "zombie" classes to pop up.

Comment: This method can still be used with a better regex, such as the one found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2644364/1333402

Answer (score 119):

A regex splitting on word boundary `\b` isn't the best solution for this:

```
var prefix = "prefix";
var classes = el.className.split(" ").filter(function(c) {
    return c.lastIndexOf(prefix, 0) !== 0;
});
el.className = classes.join(" ").trim();
```

or as a jQuery mixin:

```
$.fn.removeClassPrefix = function(prefix) {
    this.each(function(i, el) {
        var classes = el.className.split(" ").filter(function(c) {
            return c.lastIndexOf(prefix, 0) !== 0;
        });
        el.className = $.trim(classes.join(" "));
    });
    return this;
};
```

2018 ES6 Update:

```
const prefix = "prefix";
const classes = el.className.split(" ").filter(c => !c.startsWith(prefix));
el.className = classes.join(" ").trim();
```

Comment: This is better approach than using RegExp with \b (word boundary check) because it prevents 'zombie classes' from popping up. If you have classes like "prefix-suffix", the 'best answer' in this thread will leave the class '-suffix' because \b will split before '-' char.  Your split-map-join solution works around that :)

I created a tiny jQuery plugin around your solution, Kabir: (https://gist.github.com/2881585)

Comment: +1 I as well concur, every other answer appears to just be a simple regex that would break on non-space word boundaries. If I have time tomorrow I'll supply a unit test that proves this.

Comment: I like it although this actually isn't valid code, since the anonymous function in `filter` must return a boolean. This will work: `var classes = $(e).attr("class").split(" ");
                        $(classes).each(function(i, item) {
                            classes[i] = item.indexOf("prefix") === -1 ? item : "prefix-new");
                        });

                        $(e).attr("class", classes.join(" "));`

Comment: A more valid solution uses map: `$e.attr('class', $.map($e.attr('class').split(' '), function (klass) { return klass.indexOf(prefix) != 0 ? klass : undefined; }).join(' '));`

Comment: This approach works the best. I used @JakubP's plugin. One suggestion if I may: What it does, when it now returns the classes, it causes a lot of space. For instance `class="blackRow blackText orangeFace blackHead"` will return `class="   orangeFace "` if you run `removeClassPrefix("black");`. I solved this by trimming the result like so: `el.className = $.trim(classes.join(" "));`.

Answer (score 33):

I've written a simple [jQuery plugin - alterClass](https://gist.github.com/1517285), that does wildcard class removal. 
Will optionally add classes too.

```
$( '#foo' ).alterClass( 'foo-* bar-*', 'foobar' )
```

Comment: Thanks Pete! Just used your plugin and it works great...saved me some time!

Answer (score 14):

You don't need any jQuery specific code to handle this.  Just use a RegExp to replace them:

```
$("#a").className = $("#a").className.replace(/\bbg.*?\b/g, '');
```

You can modify this to support any prefix but the faster method is above as the RegExp will be compiled only once:

```
function removeClassByPrefix(el, prefix) {
    var regx = new RegExp('\\b' + prefix + '.*?\\b', 'g');
    el.className = el.className.replace(regx, '');
    return el;
}
```

Comment: If the prefix ends with a dash, you need to change the regular expression. 
`new RegExp('\\b' + prefix + '[\\S]*\\b', 'g')`

Answer (score 10):

Using [2nd signature](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/#removeClass-functionindex--class) of `$.fn.removeClass` :

```
// Considering:
var $el = $('<div class="  foo-1 a b foo-2 c foo"/>');

function makeRemoveClassHandler(regex) {
  return function (index, classes) {
    return classes.split(/\s+/).filter(function (el) {return regex.test(el);}).join(' ');
  }
}

$el.removeClass(makeRemoveClassHandler(/^foo-/));
//> [<div class=​"a b c foo">​</div>​]
```

Comment: Since jQuery v1.4, this is the best approach.

Answer (score 6):

For modern browsers:

```
let element = $('#a')[0];
let cls = 'bg';

element.classList.remove.apply(element.classList, Array.from(element.classList).filter(v=>v.startsWith(cls)));
```

Comment: using string.starsWith() (or string.endsWith()) was perfect for me!

Answer (score 4):

An approach I would use using simple jQuery constructs and array handling functions, is to declare an function that takes id of the control and prefix of the class and deleted all classed. The code is attached:

```
function removeclasses(controlIndex,classPrefix){
    var classes = $("#"+controlIndex).attr("class").split(" ");
    $.each(classes,function(index) {
        if(classes[index].indexOf(classPrefix)==0) {
            $("#"+controlIndex).removeClass(classes[index]);
        }
    });
}
```

Now this function can be called from anywhere, onclick of button or from code:

```
removeclasses("a","bg");
```

Answer (score 3):

http://www.mail-archive.com/jquery-en@googlegroups.com/msg03998.html says:

...and .removeClass() would remove all classes...

It works for me ;)

cheers

Comment: This is a better choice! Works.

Comment: The question doesn't ask how to remove all classes it asks how to remove all classes beginning with a certain string. These two things are very, very different.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for solution for exactly the same problem. To remove all classes starting with prefix "fontid_" After reading this article I wrote a small plugin which I'm using now.

```
(function ($) {
        $.fn.removePrefixedClasses = function (prefix) {
            var classNames = $(this).attr('class').split(' '),
                className,
                newClassNames = [],
                i;
            //loop class names
            for(i = 0; i < classNames.length; i++) {
                className = classNames[i];
                // if prefix not found at the beggining of class name
                if(className.indexOf(prefix) !== 0) {
                    newClassNames.push(className);
                    continue;
                }
            }
            // write new list excluding filtered classNames
            $(this).attr('class', newClassNames.join(' '));
        };
    }(fQuery));
```

Usage:

```
$('#elementId').removePrefixedClasses('prefix-of-classes_');
```

Comment: This is nothing more than my solution with 10x more lines and a less efficient "string starts with" check :-/

Answer (score 3):

In one line ...
Removes all classes that match a regular expression *someRegExp*

```
$('#my_element_id').removeClass( function() { return (this.className.match(/someRegExp/g) || []).join(' ').replace(prog.status.toLowerCase(),'');});
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old question, but I found out new solution and want to know if it has disadvantages?

```
$('#a')[0].className = $('#a')[0].className
                              .replace(/(^|\s)bg.*?(\s|$)/g, ' ')
                              .replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ')
                              .replace(/(^\s|\s$)/g, '');
```

Comment: In 2020, the disadvantage is jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Prestaul's answer was helpful, but it didn't quite work for me. The jQuery way to select an object by id didn't work. I had to use

```
document.getElementById("a").className
```

instead of

```
$("#a").className
```

Comment: or $("#a")[0].className as className is only available on the DOM element and not the jQuery object

Comment: this is a comment for someones answer, not an answer

Answer (score 1):

I also use hyphen'-' and digits for class name. So my version include '\d-'

```
$('#a')[0].className = $('#a')[0].className.replace(/\bbg.\d-*?\b/g, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(function($)
{
    return this.each(function()
    {
        var classes = $(this).attr('class');

        if(!classes || !regex) return false;

        var classArray = [];

        classes = classes.split(' ');

        for(var i=0, len=classes.length; i<len; i++) if(!classes[i].match(regex)) classArray.push(classes[i]);

        $(this).attr('class', classArray.join(' '));
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly old post. But I worked out a solution that worked for me.

```
$('[class*=classtoremove]').each(function( index ) {
    var classArray = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
    $.each( classArray, function( key, value ) {
        if(value.includes('classtoremove')) {
            console.log(value);
            $('.' + value).removeClass(value);
        }
    });
});
```

Essentially it will get any class that contains `classtoremove` regardless what is added on the end. So it could be `classtoremove234164726` or `classtoremove767657576575` it will find the two classes, split all the classes then for each class thats in the array will check to see if the value includes the class to remove. it then gets that class and removes the class without having to replace or re-add anything.

```js
$('[class*=classtoremove]').each(function( index ) {
    var classArray = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
    $.each( classArray, function( key, value ) {
        if(value.includes('classtoremove')) {
            console.log(value + ' has been removed');
            $('.' + value).removeClass(value);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='classtoremove235235235 chicken omlets wrapper'></div>
<div class='classtoremove354645745 chicken omlets wrapper'></div>
<div class='classtoremoveesdfdfh5645 chicken omlets wrapper'></div>
<div class='classtoremove3425423wdt chicken omlets wrapper'></div>
<div class='classtoremovewdgrt346 chicken omlets wrapper'></div>
<div class='classtoremovesdgsbfd4454 chicken omlets wrapper'></div>
<div class='classtoremove45454545 chicken omlets wrapper'></div>
<div class='classtoremove666eed chicken omlets wrapper'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The top answer converted to jQuery for those wanting a jQuery only solution:

```
const prefix = 'prefix'
const classes = el.attr('class').split(' ').filter(c => !c.startsWith(prefix))
el.attr('class', classes.join(' ').trim())
```

Answer (score -5):

```
$("#element").removeAttr("class").addClass("yourClass");
```

Comment: I don't think you read the question very well. The user was not asking about simply removing a class and adding another one.

Comment: @Andrew Barber: you're right this is not the right answer, but majorsk8 suggested how to clear all the classes (removeAttr), not just a single one ;)