# JQuery - remove selected class when using "Attribute starts with" selector?

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-selectors

Working with auto-generated html code, with variable classnames: `table-col-44, table-col-19, table-col-121` etc.

I've got a loop that's going through and selecting these variable classes using [this jQuery selector functionality](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
for(r in replace){
    var targ = replace[r];
    $("[class^='"+targ+"']").each(function(){
        ...
    })
}
```

The problem is, once I've selected the classes I want to scrub, I can't find a way to target them to remove them. Often these are `<p>` and `<td>` tags that have other classes that need to be preserved, so I can't just wipe the class attribute altogether. Is there a way to pass the matched class as an argument to the each() function? Or perhaps there's some kind of `$(this).removeClass([selected])` keyword that comes with jQuery? Totally stumped here. Thanks for the help!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8v7DR/

Comment: Thanks for the input. That only works if the class in question is the first class in the list - unfortunately, most of the time, that isn't the case in this code.

Comment: Your selector `"[class^='"+targ+"']"` will only select the first class.

Comment: I believe that's incorrect. I've successfully selected elements that match the 2nd or 3rd class using this method.

Comment: My mistake, you were right. *= instead of ^= is necessary to select any class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if there's a more jQuery way of doing this but you could try this inside the each:

```
var newClassName = $(this).attr('class').split(' ').slice(1).join(' ')
$(this).attr('class', newClassName)
```

This will remove the first class name since you've matched with `^=`.

Update:

See here for an example of removing a class by passing a function to removeClass: http://jsfiddle.net/DHxNG/1/. The JS is:

```
targ = 'table-col';
$('[class*="'+targ+'"]').removeClass(function(index, css) {
    var re = new RegExp(targ+"-\\d+");
    return (css.match(re) || []).join(' ');
});
```

This is based on code from here: [JQuery removeClass wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644299/jquery-removeclass-wildcard)

Comment: ^= matches all classes that start with the input string, not just the first. Looking to remove the class no matter where it appears in the classname list.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case for me, I needed to use `*=` instead of `^=`

Comment: Brilliant! That was indeed my misunderstanding. Kudos to you sir.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `startsWith` function to the `string` object's prototype, doing something like this:

```
if (typeof String.prototype.startsWith != 'function') {
    String.prototype.startsWith = function (str){
        return this.indexOf(str) == 0;
    };
}
```

Then your loop to remove the classes that start with whatever was matched on looks like this:

```
for(r in replace) {
    var targ = replace[r];
    $("[class^='"+targ+"']").each(function() {
        var $element = $(this);
        var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
        for(var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
            var cssClass = classes[i];
            if(cssClass.startsWith(targ)) {
                $element.removeClass(cssClass);
            }
        }
    });
}
```