# jQuery - remove all element classes starts on specific pattern

Tags: jquery, regex, class, tags, removeall

I need to remove all classes from element starts with 'layout-'

I try:

```
var regex = new RegExp('\b' + 'layout-' + '.*?\b', 'g');
$(el)[0].className = $(el)[0].className.replace(regex, '');
```

but it doesn't work.
Solution could be in jQuery.
Any idea?

Comment: You want to remove all classes, or just the classes that start with "layout-"? For example, `class="class1 layout-something"` - should this keep `class1`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery removeClass wildcard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644299/jquery-removeclass-wildcard)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The RegExp you have posted in the question is not working because the `\b` is not escaped as `\\b`. Hence the actual RegExp is becoming `/layout-.*?/g` instead of `/\blayout-.*?\b/g`. Doing the below change would work.

```
var regex = new RegExp('\\b' + 'layout-' + '.+?\\b', 'g');
```

---

You can also try like the below. This removes all classes that are like `layout-X`

```
var regex = /(\s)*(layout-.*?)(?=\s)/g; 
$('#test')[0].className = $('#test')[0].className.replace(regex, '');
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/qgA9V/)

**Input:** `class=sample layout-10 layout-9 sample1 slayout`

**Output:** `class=sample sample1 slayout`

**RegExp Explained:**

`\s` - Any whitespace character

`(layout-.*?)` - Capture all values like layout-X where X can be any character any number of times

`(?=\s)` - Look ahead upto the next whitespace character (meaning till end of word)

---

As pointed out by musefan in the comments `var regex = /\blayout-.+?\b/g;` will also do the job.

Comment: Was just about to post an answer suggesting that it seems to be a problem with the regex definition. This regex also seems to work: `/\blayout-.+?\b/g`

Comment: Right, true. Just now re-checked after you posted. Also, the one I posted needs improvement to `(\s)*` initially. The current one in my answer wont replace `layout-X` if it is the first class. Correcting it now.

Comment: @musefan: Ah got it, the regex in question is not working because the `\b` isn't escaped as `\\b` :D Because of that the actual regex that is formed is becoming `/layout-.+?/g`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("[class^='layout-']").removeAttr('class');
```

reference [attribute-starts-with-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

**[removeAttr](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)**

Comment: I am not sure if the OP wants to remove the whole class attribute, I have asked for clarification, but there attempt seems to suggest they just want to remove the `layout-` classes

Comment: I need to remove all classes from element starts with 'layout-' op said and i have answer this thanks for focus @musefan

Comment: The example code also suggests that the OP already has the element, so may not even need a selector at all... it's not a very well explained question to be fair

Comment: @musefan: Yep, agreed. Initially I thought the same as you did, but re-reading it tells me that Rituraj has a point.