# Replace the class's suffix while preserving its prefix

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to replace the class's suffix while preserving its prefix

DEMO:
http://jsbin.com/vozufura/4/edit

The desired code should make all the div black.
So that:

- class= menu-456 AND menu-789 should be replaced and become menu-123
- All the div should be black as a result

HTML:

```
  <div class="menu-123">black</div>
  <div class="menu-456">green</div>
  <div class="menu-789" >red</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu-123 {
  background: black;
}

.menu-456 {
background: green;
}

.menu-789 {
  background: red;
}
```

Javascript (Jquery):

```
 /* I am not looking for javascript like removeClass nor addClass, 
nor do i want to change the background. 
I wanted to know if it is possible to REPLACE the suffix of a class*/
```

Comment: I'd recommend taking a look at Codecademy to help you start off with the JavaScript: http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/javascript .

Comment: Different ways of changing the bg colour to black. You can just set the bg colour in js and it will work.

Comment: I understand, the "change to background" is just a demo. I want to replace the suffix of the class in a more complex coding that is not display here in demo.

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of [removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) and [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) functions provided by jQuery, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".menu-456,.menu-789").removeClass("menu-456 menu-789").addClass("menu-123");
});
```

This code runs when the DOM is loaded and what it does is as follows:

1. It selects all elements with either class `menu-456` or `menu-789`.
2. It removes classes `menu-456` and `menu-789` from those elements.
3. It gives the elements the class `menu-123`.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/61eup0w2/)**

Answer (score 0):

your jquery 
JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $('[class^=menu-]').not('.menu-123').removeClass().addClass('menu-123');
});
```

you can you [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/as37w7bp/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Changing and messing with classes is easy with jQuery.
Take a look at [.addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) [.removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/).
You can use the [Attribute Contains Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) or [Attribute Contains Prefix Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/) to be more general and effective in your code.

For example, if you want `menu-123` to be the only new class on the element:

```
$("div[class|='menu']").attr('class', 'menu-123');
```

or, if you want to get clever:

```
$("div[class|='menu']").attr('class', function(i, c){
  return c.replace(/(^|\s)menu-\S+/g, 'menu-123');
});
```

thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2644364/2789806).