# How to remove all classes which are created dynamically using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want remove classes which are created dynamically using jQuery.

I have a dynamic classes in table like:

```
   "dynamicHeader","record1","record2","record3"
```

I want to remove all classes class name contain 'record'.
Thanks Advance.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$("*").removeClass (function (index, css) {
    return (css.match (/(^|\s)record-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this post can help you 
[same request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644299/jquery-removeclass-wildcard)

```
$("*").removeClass (function (index, css) {
return (css.match (/\brecord-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
});
```

Comment: This answer has already been posted. With slightly different regex.

Comment: Yes it is posted but just link some equivalent questions

Comment: Which doesn't really seem to add to the answer. The link you provided adds little to no additional information. I'm not trying to be offensive, I just don't see the value.