# How to match "modal-sucess" part using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

This is my HTML div tag

```
<div class="modal modal-success"  id="myModal">
```

I want to add or remove class dynamically using jQuery. I want to match only the the `model-*` ( eg model-success , modal-danger etc ) part and remove that part whenever want

For example

```
<div class="modal "  id="myModal">
$('#myModal').addClass("modal-"+messageType);
//message type will be success , warning
```

After adding that I want to remove that newly added part dynamically

```
 <div class="modal modal-success " id="myModal">
```

I want to keep the `modal` part as it is and remove the `modal-sucess` part

How can I do this using jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `.removeClass();` with a parameter of the class you wish to remove it will only remove the class specified, eg: `.removeClass('modal-' + messageType);` will remove `'.modal-success'`, `'.modal-warning'` etc. depending on the variable value.

If you use `.removeClass();` with no parameters then it will remove all classes.

See the docs for a more comprehensive explanation https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/

Comment: Thank you ! can i use .removeClass('modal-*') to remove a class starting from  modal- ?

Comment: I don't think you can use wildcard selectors in the `.removeClass();` function. You may find some more information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644299/jquery-removeclass-wildcard