# jQuery Find and Replace all instances of part of a classname

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several div's with a classname that looks like this:

```
class="col-md-4"
```

some have:

```
class="col-md-12"
```

What I want to do is to search for whatever the number at the end of the class is and replace all of them to:

```
class="col-md-6"
```

How can I do this using jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use "contains" selector like this

```
$("[class*='col-md-']").removeClass (function (index, css) {
    return (css.match (/(^|\s)col-md-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
}).addClass("col-md-6");
```

removeClass function based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644299/jquery-removeclass-wildcard)

```
$("[class*='col-md-']")
```

will find any element with a class that contains `col-md-`.
The `removeClass` function will than remove it. And finally col-md-6 will be added.

### EDIT

changed [class^='col-md-'] to  [class*='col-md-'] in case class attribute has another class before col-md-. Thank you @dfsq for pointing this out

Comment: Isn't this just a slightly modified copy of @TimVermaelen answer? Except Tim posted his 10 mins earlier?!?!

Comment: It is actually the same answer! even the same link. When I started to write the answer Tim's answer wasn't there though..

Answer (score 3):

You can use special selectors in jQuery:
`^=` starts with ...
`*=` contains ...
Or use a combination of both selectors if you don't get them all.

```
var cols = $('[class^="col-md-"]');
```

Then to [remove all classes with a wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644299/jquery-removeclass-wildcard)

```
cols.removeClass(function (index, css) {
    return (css.match (/(^|\s)col-md-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
});
```

Then add the class you want:

```
cols.addClass('col-md-6');
```

Comment: Not reliable, as it will not work for `class="something col-md-4"`.

Comment: Of course it's **not**. I gave you an example of when it will not work. Moreover, `*=` is not ends-with selector.

Comment: You're right about the `*=` which is "contains" selector.
Then again, what is still *not* reliable?

Comment: This solution expects specific structure for class attribute (col- class to be the first). And this is not reliable.

Comment: "Or use a combination of both selectors if you don't get them all." ... I'm done with this now.

Comment: @dfsq it works even when its not the first. its global match. you can test it yourself https://regex101.com/

Comment: @ShiranDror I was talking about `[class^="col-md-"]` selector. You should use `[class*="col-md-"]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the class and add the new one:

```
$(".col-md-4").removeClass("col-md-4").addClass("col-md-6");
$(".col-md-12").removeClass("col-md-12").addClass("col-md-6");
```

Comment: What I need is a bit different. I need to do this without knowing the last number of the class, just what I want to change it to. For example, I would just know this part: col-md-  but not the number.

Answer (score 0):

This should also work:

```
$('[class*=col-md]').removeClass('col-md-4 col-md-12').addClass('col-md-6');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with simple javascript if all of those elements were inside a main `div`.

For example:

```
var arr_divs = document.getElementById('main_div').getElementsByTagName('div');

for(var i = 0; i < arr_divs.length; i++){

    if(arr_divs.item(i).className == 'col-md-12' || arr_divs.item(i).className == 'col-md-4'){

        arr_divs.item(i).className = 'col-md-6';
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most efficient way of doing what you want but, it keeps it simple. Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lns1ob5q/

```
$("[class^=col-md-]").attr("class", "col-md-6");
```

The above selects all elements with a class containing `col-md-` (`[class^=col-md-]`) and replaces the class, regardless of what number immediately follows, with `col-md-6`.

The reason I say it's not efficient is becuase jQuery will initially pick up elements that already have a class of `col-md-6` and replace their class with the same one... But hey, it works!