# How to use jQuery wildcards with removeClass

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to modify a div that has a given class with the following jquery code:

```
$("[class^=delay-][class$='+number+']").each(function(index) {
    var delayTime = $(this).attr('class').match(/delay-(\d+)/)[1];
    $(this).removeClass("[class^=delay-][class$='+number+']");
    $(this).data('data-wow-delay', delayTime + 's');
});
```

1. Find the divs that has delay-1, or delay-3, and so on...
2. Get the number as a variable.
3. Remove the class because I don't need it anymore.
4. Add to the div data-wow-delay="1s"

I am using the above script but it doesn't seem to succeed in identifying the class.

Comment: because removeClass is not built to do that, there is no "selector" as an option.

Comment: $("[class^=delay-][class$='+number+']") this selector doesn't seem correct...are you trying to match elements with class delay-[number]?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to find the elements that starts with delay- and ends with a number. @klikas

Comment: Would $("[class^=delay-]") not work on it's own? Are there other elements with classes that start with delay- but not end with a number?

Comment: You should try a dynamic class selector by using number variable. `$("div.delay-"+number)`

Comment: Your selector won't work if you add any other classes.  eg `<div class='delay-1 otherclass'>`.   Instead, get all the classes and loop through them, which also gives you the exact class for `.removeClass()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> jquery wildcards don't work with removeClass

This is correct, because removeClass doesn't use a selector, it uses explicit class names - it's directly equivalent would be addClass, for which it makes no sense to have wildcards.

You can get all the classes and loop through them, giving an exact value for remove class, and, in your case for the delayTime value.

```
// match where all the classes might contain a relevant one
$("[class*='delay-']").each(function() {

  // Keep 'this' for inside later loop
  var el = $(this);

  // get all the classes
  var classList = el.attr('class').split(/\s+/);

  // loop each class to check if it's one to remove
  $.each(classList, function(index, item) {
    if (item.startsWith("delay-")) {
      el.removeClass(item);
      var delayTime = parseInt(item.substring(6), 10);
      el.data('data-wow-delay', delayTime + 's');
    }
  });
});
```

You could reduce the code with `$.map`, but this gives the idea.

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hne72o8m/

Comment: It is working for removeClass, but it isn't adding the data-wow-delay, and I can't figure it out.

Comment: How are you reading the data-wow-delay?   When you use $.data, it adds/removes `data-` for you, so `$.data("data-wow-delay")` would be the same as `$.prop("data-data-wow-delay")`  Try without the "data-" prefix in the data name.

Comment: Nothing, it doesn't work in the fiddle either. I want to add data-wow-delay="2s" to the div.

Comment: Works fine in the fiddle.  Here's an update: https://jsfiddle.net/hne72o8m/1/  1 click the div - undefined, 2 click the button to add the data, 3 click the div - shows the value.

Comment: *Exactly* how are you reading/looking for "data-wow-delay"?  It won't appear in the html, if you're looking the browser debugger (F12).

Comment: I was looking with the browser debugger. But I need to add this data to the html in order to use it later with other JS library. Is it possible?

Comment: That's now how `$.data()` works.  You could try `.prop` and/or `.attr` which might give you what you need.

Comment: It works perfectly using in the last line: `el.attr('data-wow-delay', delayTime + 's');`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `removeClass` function takes a function argument since jQuery 1.4.

So it can be done with a one-liner. See Best answer in [jQuery removeClass wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644299/jquery-removeclass-wildcard)