# Remove classes from output list category from Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using `wp_list_categories` to output my categories in Wordpress. The results are:

```
<ul>
  <li class="cat-item cat-item-1"><a href=".." >..</a></li>
  <li class="cat-item cat-item-8"><a href=".." >..</a></li>
  <li class="cat-item cat-item-10"><a href=".." >..</a></li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to remove these default classes on the list items? So to remove `cat-item` and `cat-item-#`?
Thanks!

Comment: The default class you mean the `cat-item cat-item-1` ?

Comment: yes that's what i mean :)

Comment: jquery for doing it afterwards: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644299/jquery-removeclass-wildcard

Comment: Well  using JQuery you could iterate through the `ul` children and remove their classes using `$(element).removeClass()`

Comment: Using jQuery feels a bit backwards as the output of the php is stil the same. That way i will be adding it and then remove it immediately. I don't want to add it in the first place. Is there a way to hook into Wordpress like one would do when removing body classes?