# jQuery/Javascript toggle between a bunch of classes on body tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a bunch of spans in my HTML structure with different ID's and i want to toggle classes on body tag by each of the span ID's
For example if i click on a span with **ID_0** I want to toggle class **ID_0** on body tag
and if i click on **ID_1** then remove the other ones and add the one i clicked

```js
$(".images").click(function(){
      var ids = $(this).attr("id");
      $("body").removeClass("ID_0 ID_1 ID_2 ID_3").addClass(ids);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
  <div class="Container">
    <span class="images" id="ID_0">ID_0</span>
    <span class="images" id="ID_1">ID_1</span>
    <span class="images" id="ID_2">ID_2</span>
    <span class="images" id="ID_3">ID_3</span>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The spans are auto generated with php and each of the spans have its own ID's there might be +15 spans like that, So im pretty sure you can do way better than my newbie jquery coding :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery removeClass wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644299/jquery-removeclass-wildcard)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below will remove any class that starts with `ID_` since this is your "wildcard"

```
$("body").removeClass(function(index, className) {
    return (className.match(/(^|\s)ID_\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
});
```

```js
$(".images").click(function() {
  var ids = $(this).attr("id");
  $("body").removeClass(function(index, className) {
    return (className.match(/(^|\s)ID_\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
  });
  $("body").addClass(ids);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="Container">
    <span class="images" id="ID_0">ID_0</span>
    <span class="images" id="ID_1">ID_1</span>
    <span class="images" id="ID_2">ID_2</span>
    <span class="images" id="ID_3">ID_3</span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you want override the classes of the body every time, yes? I think it's most convenient with vanilla JavaScript. See snippet below.

```js
$(".images").click(function(){
      var ids = $(this).attr("id");
      document.body.classList = ''; // Empty class list
      document.body.classList += ids; // Could merge the two statements into document.body.classList = ids;
      console.log(document.body.classList); // debugging
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
  <div class="Container">
    <span class="images" id="ID_0">ID_0</span>
    <span class="images" id="ID_1">ID_1</span>
    <span class="images" id="ID_2">ID_2</span>
    <span class="images" id="ID_3">ID_3</span>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What if body has a class, let's say "blue" then you would also remove that

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Yep. This was how I understood the question. But I admit, I prefer your answer (have my upvote).

Comment: No i don't want to empty the body classes, I have a bunch of other css classes using in body tag this will empty all on clicking :D Sorry if my post was confusing, the html structure was just to show what im trying to do :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```js
$(".images").click(function(){
      var ids = $(this).attr("id");
      $("body").attr("class","").addClass(ids);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
  <div class="Container">
    <span class="images" id="ID_0">ID_0</span>
    <span class="images" id="ID_1">ID_1</span>
    <span class="images" id="ID_2">ID_2</span>
    <span class="images" id="ID_3">ID_3</span>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, this will empty body classes on clicking,This will cause issues because i have a lot of css classes using in body tag