# How to remove className if we know only the part of className?

Tags: javascript, html, css

For example - I have just the next line of code, where I need to recorgonize if the `span` have the some `class` included that begins from the `outcome--active`. And if so - delete it via `JS`.

```
<span class="outcome___259Az outcome--active___1Ffc-"></span>
```

Any ideas how we can make it?

I had tried next, but it does not work:

```
document.querySelector('[class^="outcome"]').classList.remove(/outcome--active/g)
```

Comment: possible (jquery) duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644299/jquery-removeclass-wildcard

Comment: @TemaniAfif I do need jQuery solution! Just pure JS

Comment: @TemaniAfif he is using vanilla javascript. not jquery

Comment: that's why I only said *possible jquery duplicate* ... I didn't close the quesiton, the jQuery method may interest other people and it may give idea for any JS implementation

Comment: @patelarpan I know, and i didn't close :) I was clear, that this a duplicate with a jQuery method ... for future reference

Comment: Reeks of design flaw, maybe? Why is that random/changing part in the classname?

Comment: Given that both of those class-names start with the string `outcome` how do you determine which, if any, of those class-names should be removed from the element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately according to the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) the `<element>.classList.remove()` method requires a *`<string>`* argument and it doesn't accept a *`<RegExp>`*.

So you could simply replace the whole className of the element by removing the class starting with `outcome--active<something>`

```
let outcome = document.querySelector('[class^="outcome"]')
outcome.className = outcome.className.replace(/\boutcome--active.+?/g, '');
```

> [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bMQNbN)

Comment: This would target only the elements whose class attribute starts exactly with`"outcome"`, if there is an other class set before, or even just a space, then it won't match. Also, in your codepen, the rule `[class="outcome--active___1Ffc-"]` never matches, and `:not([class="outcome--active___1Ffc-"])` always matches, js or not.

Comment: in fact. the codepen shows that the class has been properly removed while the other classes have been kept

Comment: No, it doesn't show anything that's my point. Your element's class attribute is never set to the string `"outcome--active___1Ffc-"`. You could have written `:not(*){color:red}*{color:green}` and it would do exactly the same.

Comment: ...try to remove your js. Is anything red?

Comment: ok, i see, Just forgot `~` in my css but the code works as expected. (Remove the js, now the span is in red)

Comment: Better, but your js selector should be improved too in order to catch the elements which have an other class set before, or [even just a space](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WJYbBE). (`'[class^="outcome"],[class*=" outcome"]'` should do it)

Answer (score 1):

Using the following function, you can delete the desired class by knowing a part of that class name, from the class list:

```js
function removeClassByString( part ) {
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName( 'span' );

    for ( var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++ ) {
        var classList = elements[i].className.split( ' ' );
        var count = classList.length;

        for ( var j = 0; j < count; j++ ) {
            if ( classList[j].search( part ) != -1 ) {
                delete classList.splice( j, 1 )
            }
        }

        if ( count != classList.length ) {
            var el = document.createElement( 'i' );
            el.innerText = '         (class removed!)'
        } else {
            var el = document.createElement( 'i' );
            el.innerText = '  (no change)'
        }

        elements[i].appendChild( el );

        elements[i].className = classList.join( ' ' )
    }
}
```

```css
span {
    display: block;
    font: normal 1em "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace
}
i {
    color: green
}
.outcome--active___1Ffc- {
    color: red
}
```

```html
<span class="outcome--active___1Ffc-">The phrase exists in the class name.</span>
<span class="outcome___259Az">The phrase does'nt exist in the class name.</span>
<span class="outcome___259Az outcome">The phrase does'nt exist in the class name.</span>
<span class="outcome___259Az outcome--active___1Ffc-">The phrase exists in the class name.</span>
<br />
<input name="" type="button" value="Remove Class" onclick="removeClassByString( 'outcome--active' )" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way.

1. split your classes  into an array
2. using javascript `some` method test if a particular class is available or not.
3. if available then delete the element.

```js
if(document.querySelector('[class^="outcome"]').className.split(' ').some(c => /outcome--/g.test(c) )) {
    document.querySelector('[class^="outcome"]').remove();
}
```

```html
<span class="outcome___259Az outcome--active___1Ffc-">test</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="outcome___259Az outcome--active___1Ffc-"></span>

<script>

// List with span's classes
var classList = document.querySelector('[class^="outcome"]').classList;

//  List with classes to remove
var removeClassList = [];

//  Get classes that matches with regexp
classList.forEach( function(value) {
    var result = /([^ ]*)(outcome--active)([^ ]*)/g.test(value);
  if(result){
    removeClassList.push(value);
  }
});

//  Remove classes that matches with regexp from span
removeClassList.forEach( function(value) {
    document.querySelector('[class^="outcome"]').classList.remove(value);
});
</script>
```