# jquery UI disable theme styling

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I was wondering, how can I make jquery UI not to adds any class when it initializes the `$.tabs()` ?

This is my html structure

```
<link href="smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
...
<link href="estilos_scoreboard.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
...

<div id="tab_container">
    <ul class="ui-tabs-nav">
        <li><a href="#tab_equipos"><span>Equipos</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab_jugadores"><span>Jugadores</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab_partidos"><span>Partidos</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab_directos"><span>Directos</span></a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tab_equipos">... cargando ...</div>
    <div id="tab_jugadores">... cargando ...</div>
    <div id="tab_partidos">... cargando ...</div>
    <div id="tab_directos">... cargando ...</div>       
</div>
```

javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div#tab_container').tabs();
    $('div#tab_equipos').load('lv_equipos.php');
});
```

In `estilos_scoreboard.css` I have my css styles which works great if I don't load `smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css`

So I was wondering, is there any way to tell `$.tabs()` not to apply none of its styling?

//note: I am asking this because I'm not the one that code it this way, but the one to apply quick fixes and I need `smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css` for jquery UI Autocomplete and other features

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I decided for know just to use a simple if:

```
<?php if($_ADM['mod'] == 'scoreboard') {  ?>
    <link href="estilos_scoreboard.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<?php } else { ?>
    <link href="<?=BASE_URL;?>assets/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Also a possibility, but you still keep the `ui-*` in your code.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, this cannot be done through default code/options. You can, however, just remove all jQuery classes after applying tabs.

The jQuery library uses the prefix `ui-` for all classes, so you can remove all those classes at once after applying your tabs / plugin.

This should work:

```
removeByClassPrefix(document.getElementById("element"), "ui-");

function removeClassByPrefix(el, prefix) {
    var regx = new RegExp('\\b' + prefix + '.*?\\b', 'g');
    el.className = el.className.replace(regx, '');
    return el;
}
```

Or:

```
$("#element").className = $("#element").className.replace(/\bui-.*?\b/g, '');
```

Above function thanks to `Prestaul` for this answer: [Remove all classes that begin with a certain string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57812/jquery-remove-all-classes-that-begin-with-a-certain-string)

Comment: Try this instead: $("#element").attr("class", $("#element").attr("class").replace(/\bui-\S+\b/g, ''));