# jQuery selector on multiple classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

This finds the id but does not remove the class

```
$('[id^=paritalIDname]').removeClass('[class^=partialClassName]');
```

Probably because the element looks like

```
<div id="partialIDname-full" class="something someone partialClassNameFull">
```

Whether the element has a class name of `partialClassNameFull` or `partialClassNameHalf` I need to remove it.

I thought I could use a wildcard in the class selector, like

```
removeClass('[class^=partialClassName*]');
```

but that's not working.

What is a good solution?  (Thanks.)

Comment: You can't do pattern matches on class names. Instead, arrange for there to be two classes: "partialClassName" and "partialClassNameFull".

Comment: Hey... using the first line of code in your question and the info you can glean from this answer to a similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/a/57819/414972) can you get something that will work?

Comment: I would use `filter()` with a quick regex like `$els.filter(function(){ return /partialClassName/.test(this.className) })`

Comment: If there is only two classes and you want them removed why not just use `removeClass('partialClassNameFull partialClassNameHalf')` whichever class is present will be removed.

Comment: @Musa it's more complicated than that...

Comment: Thank you, @elclanrs I can see that working, but I went with jules suggestion and made a helper function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will handle all partial match.

```
        $("div[id^=partialId]").each(function () {
            var cls = $(this).attr("class").split(" ");

            for (var i in cls) {
                if (/partialClass/.test(cls[i])) {
                    $(this).removeClass(cls[i]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Yep, and that's what I needed - "all" partial matches. Thanks Jules!  (BTW, you remove the break and return below to make sure you get through the for loop.)  -- but you knew that.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly remove both classes:

```
$('[id^=partialIDname]').removeClass('partialClassNameFull').removeClass('partialClassNameHalf');
```

Because .removeClass() only works on full class name matches.  If one of the class names is not present, then nothing will happen - no error is thrown when you try to .removeClass() a class that is not present.

You can also try out as suggested in the comments the briefer version of:

```
$('[id^=partialIDname]').removeClass('partialClassNameFull partialClassNameHalf');
```

Comment: You could improve this slightly: $('[id^=partialIDname]').removeClass('partialClassNameFull partialClassNameHalf');

Comment: If it were only two class names then I would not bother asking the question.  The need for the solution arose when building a multi-form page that manipulated the DOM extensively in order to ease the user into the required information being sought.  The ability to remove several classes by calling a filtered class name made it easier to handle the various stages.