# Javascript / jQuery: How do I remove a range of numbered classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove all classes that begin with a certain string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57812/remove-all-classes-that-begin-with-a-certain-string)

I have a script which adds one of six classes randomly to the body. The classes are numbered between 1 and 6, like this:

`theme-1` to `theme-6`.

I need a clean way to remove all of them. Right now I have this:

```
$('body').removeClass('theme-1');
$('body').removeClass('theme-2');
$('body').removeClass('theme-3');
$('body').removeClass('theme-4');
$('body').removeClass('theme-5');
$('body').removeClass('theme-6');
```

But it's kind of clunky right? Is there a way I can say "remove any classes between `theme-1` to `theme-6`"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the loop index to generate class names.

```
classes = ""
for(i=1; i < 7; i++)
   classes += 'theme-' + i + " ";
$('body').removeClass(classes);
```

Comment: Why call `.removeClass` function 6 times when it can accept multiple class and remove it all in 1 call?

Comment: Thanks Vega, I removed this.

Answer (score 1):

You could combine it all in to one line:

```
$('body').removeClass('theme-1 theme-2 theme-3 theme-4 theme-5 theme-6');
```

Or use a loop, though if the classes are **always** between 1 and 6 the loop seems like overkill personally.

Answer (score 0):

You could clear them in a loop, which is, at least, a little cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how many of those you might have, you should use a regex:

```
document.body.className = document.body.className.replace(/(^| )theme-\d+( |$)/g, ' ');
```

---

If you want to stay within the jQuery API, use this:

```
$('body').attr('class', function (i, className) {
    return className.replace(/(^| )theme-\d+( |$)/g, ' ');
});
```

---

If you don't have any other classes on the `body`, you can remove them all in one fell swoop:

```
$('body').removeClass();
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57812/remove-all-classes-that-begin-with-a-certain-string).  The code from `Pat` is as follows:

```
$('body')[0].className.replace(/\theme-.*?\b/g, '');
```

But this answer from `Prestaul` looks good as well. Use this function:

```
function removeClassByPrefix(el, prefix) {
    var regx = new RegExp('\\b' + prefix + '.*?\\b', 'g');
    el.className = el.className.replace(regx, '');
    return el;
}
```

Comment: Then why haven't you closed this question as a duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').removeClass('theme-1 theme-2 theme-3 theme-4 theme-5 theme-6');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Yms5M/