# Removing all classes starting with string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="cols someclass"></div> <!--like this cols1, cols2, etc..-->
<div class="columns someclass"></div> <!--like this columns1, columns2, etc...-->
<div class="col-1 someclass"></div> <!--like this col-2, col-3,etc...-->
<div class="column-1 someclass"></div> <!--like this column-2, column-3, etc...-->
```

How to remove all classes starting with `"col"`?

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57812/remove-all-classes-that-begin-with-a-certain-string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe there is no jQuery magic for this, so here's my solution:

```
$('[class*=col]').each(function() {
    this.className = $.grep(this.className.split(' '), function(el) {
        return !/^col/.test(el);
    }).join(' ');
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cL5LJ/6/)

Basically, it selects elements that have `col` in their classes and iterate over them, iterating over their classes and removing those that begin with `col`.

Or without regex:

```
$('[class*=col]').each(function() {
    this.className = $.grep(this.className.split(' '), function(cl) {
        return cl.lastIndexOf('col', 0);
    }).join(' ');
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cL5LJ/5/)

Using a modified version of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4579228/1331430). `lastIndexOf` will return `0` if the class starts with `col` which is a falsy value and thus `grep` will remove it. If the class does not begin with `col`, then `-1` is returned which is a truthy value. You can use `return cl.lastIndexOf('col', 0) !== 0;` for a bit extra readability as well.

Or with regex only:

```
$('[class*=col]').each(function() {
    this.className = this.className.replace(/(^| )col[^ ]*/g, '');
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cL5LJ/6/)

Matches `col` at beginning of the string or after a space, removes it together with all leading characters up to another space or end of the string.

---

### *Referece*

- [`jQuery.grep`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) - Finds the elements of an array which satisfy a filter function. The original array is not affected.
- [`element.className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.className) - gets and sets the value of the `class` attribute of the specified element.

---

Of course, this selector is not optimal - if an element has `foocol` the `$('[class*=col]')` will select it, but the `$.grep`/regex will not remove it as it does not begin with `col`. I can't think of any better selector (there's no attribute selector to select a value beginning with a partial string in a space-separated list AFAIK), nevertheless this should suffice just fine.